# Generate random numbers of type T

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program that holds a `list<T>` where `T` is either `int` or `double`. I want to make a function, using components from the header `<random>`, that generates numbers of type `T`. I can't find a distribution that takes `T` as template argument.

The function is then going to be used in a call to the `generate` function:

```
generate(myList.begin(), myList.end(), RandomGenerator())
```

How do I go about doing this?

I have tried to create a class called `RandomGenerator` and overload the `operator()` for it.
When i try to pass an argument to the overloaded `operator()` i get an error.

Function call, `Random(b)` is a function object with `int` argument `b`:

```
generate(rList.begin(), rList.end(), Random(b));
```

Code for overloading `()`, where `n` is sort of a "dummy"-variable for just telling what type it is:

```
int operator()(int n)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1000, 2000);
    return dist(gen);
}
```

Error message:

```
Error   2   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'Random'    

Error   3   error C2780: 'void std::generate(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,_Fn0)' : expects 3 arguments - 2 provided
```

Comment: What did you try? (Hint: you need overload the function)

Comment: I think you may find a combination of [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and the type-class tests such as [`std::is_floating_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) and [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) useful in this endeavor.

Comment: You claim to be calling `generate` with three arguments - but the compiler says you only passed two. This strongly suggests the code you have shown is not the code you are actually compiling. Show the exact line that the error message refers to.

Comment: That is the exakt line, it point to line number 111 and that is it.

Comment: Added another error message that was unintendedly missed in earlier edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Joey's answer, the following should play nicely with `std::generate`. Disclaimer: I'm terrible at metaprogramming, please do point out any mistakes or possible improvements. This is a C++11 solution, with C++14 it would be a bit shorter.

[Live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b48b67688c8b973).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
class random_generator {
    using distribution_type = typename std::conditional<
            std::is_integral<T>::value,
            std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
            std::uniform_real_distribution<T>
        >::type;

    std::default_random_engine engine;
    distribution_type distribution;

public:
    auto operator()() -> decltype(distribution(engine)) {
        return distribution(engine);
    }
};

template<typename Container, typename T = typename Container::value_type>
auto make_generator(Container const&) -> decltype(random_generator<T>()) {
    return random_generator<T>();
}

int main() {
    auto l = std::list<double>(10);

    std::generate(std::begin(l), std::end(l), make_generator(l));    

    for (auto i : l) {
        std::cout << i << " ";    
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach more than mine. Given a vote up! :)

Answer (score 3):

Not an elegant solution but does what you want: (Modifying the code so that it can be used with generate)

```
template <typename Distribution>
class RandomGenerator
{
    using Type = typename Distribution::result_type;

    const Type getRandom(const Type& lower, const Type& upper) const
    {
        static std::default_random_engine generator;
        static Distribution distribution(lower, upper);

        return distribution(generator);
    }

public:
    RandomGenerator(const Type& lowerBound, const Type& upperBound) : _lowerBound(lowerBound), _upperBound(upperBound) { }

    const Type operator()() const
    {
        return getRandom(_lowerBound, _upperBound);
    }

private:
    Type _lowerBound;
    Type _upperBound;
};

int main()
{
    RandomGenerator<std::uniform_int_distribution<>> randomIntGenerator(1, 10);
    RandomGenerator<std::uniform_real_distribution<>> randomDoubleGenerator(0.0, 10.0);

    std::deque<int> intRandoms(10);
    std::generate(intRandoms.begin(), intRandoms.end(), randomIntGenerator);

    std::deque<double> doubleRandoms(5);
    std::generate(doubleRandoms.begin(), doubleRandoms.end(), randomDoubleGenerator);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course if we want different numbers for each run we can set the seed for default_random_engine to something like time(0) but I'll leave that one out.

Comment: You should just use `typename Distribution::result_type`.

Comment: Of course you're absolutely right; we can eliminate the extra typename Type parameter and introduce a typedef as: typedef typename Distribution::result_type Type;

Comment: If I may suggest the `using` syntax instead of `typedef` for a more C++11-ish experience. Also, both method could be made `const`.

Comment: Thanks for pointint it out. I completely forgot about 'using'. Code updated.

Comment: I have no possibility to try it out for a couple of hours and im courious, does this work with function generate?